# Drawing Highcharts - bullet graph in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, highcharts, angular8

I am using Highcharts and showing multiple graphs. But I see a different option for `Bullet Graph`using `Highcharts.setOptions`. I am not getting how to set `Highcharts.setOptions` along with existing code.

In the TS file -

```
import { chart } from 'highcharts';
import { Chart, ChartModule } from 'angular-highcharts';

chart_accessor_review = new Chart({    
    chart: {
        type: 'sankey',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    accessibility: {
        point: {
            valueDescriptionFormat: '{index}. {point.from} to {point.to}, {point.weight}.'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
        data: [
            ['Algorithm', '34220', 0],
            ['Algorithm', '34223', 21],
            ['Algorithm', '34224', 0],
            ['Algorithm', '34224', 15],
            ['Algorithm', '34233', 10],
            ['Algorithm', '34245', 7],
            ['Algorithm', '34274', 0],
            ['Algorithm', '34334', 8],
            ['Algorithm', '35319', 0],
            ['All', '34220', 1209],
            ['All', '34223', 49],
            ['All', '34224', 1990],
            ['All', '34224', 784],
            ['All', '34233', 1689],
            ['All', '34245', 455],
            ['All', '34274', 1439],
            ['All', '34334', 49],
            ['All', '35319', 1890]
        ],
        type: undefined,
        name: 'Accessor Info',
        nodeWidth: 250
    }]
});
```

and in the HTML file it is simple

```
<div [chart]="chart_accessor_review "></div>
```

I want to achieve exactly like this one - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p2zwf6e8/ But in the example they use `Highcharts.setOptions` which I am unable to use with `new Chart({})`

Comment: Just to let you know, you are currently using the 'angular-highcharts' which is a 3rd party product that is not officially supported. I will encourage you to check out the `highcharts-angular` wrapper, that was created and supported by the Highsoft. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

Comment: If you want to achieve similar results using the `highcharts-angular` you could just update the `chartOptions` instead of calling the Highcharts.setOptions() method. Live https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-rkghcb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I have set up this below in app.module.ts `import Highchartsbullet from 'highcharts/modules/bullet';` and 'Highchartsbullet(Highcharts);'. now the bullet chart is appearing

Comment: That's great to hear! So the issue was related to the missing modules.

Comment: yes, but the issue is half fixed. I am still not clear how to use `setOptions` in new object of `Chart`. I somehow fit series and data and plotbands to make that graph work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the `angular-highcharts`. I would suggest contacting `angular-highcharts` author.